# Give an example of a non-regular language $L$ such that $L^*$ is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I can't think of an example of a non-regular language $L$ such that $L^*$ is regular. . Any help ?

Comment: Take a non-regular language $L$ over an alphabet $\Sigma$. Consider the language $L'=L\cup \Sigma$. The language $L'$ is not regular, but $L'\,^*$ is regular since it is equal to $\Sigma^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $L=\{a^nb^n|n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \{a,b\}$

It's not hard to see that while $L$ is not regular, $L^*=\Sigma^*$.

Comment: What do you mean by the union of $\{a,b\}$ with $L=\{a^nb^n|n\in \mathbb N\}$ ? I never saw a language defined like that.